# UITableview:Auto resize prototype cell through Interface Builder not resizing Properly

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, autoresize

I have to make iPhone app compatible to iPhone 4s,5,5s,6,6+ for which i am using Autoresizing mask property from Interface Builder.

I have a tableview whose autoresizing mask is flexible width and flexible height then inside it i have a Prototype Cell whose autoresizing mask is again flexible width and flexible height.
then inside content view i have an image view whose autoresizing mask is again flexible width and flexible height.

When i see it in preview in Xcode 6.1 its shows everything at perfect position but when i run it on device or simulator it increases the width and height of UIImageview on each device.

Don't know why its happening. Help appreciated...

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the xib/storyboard file inside Xcode? I guess trying thins out with Auto Layout will result in easier management os such things like resizing and positioning.